# How to get rid of these from Eclipse tool bar?

Tags: eclipse

[image: Eclipse tool bar]

I tried to get rid of them from Customize Perspective but they are not even showing in there. How do I remove them??

THANKS!!

Here is Tool Bar Visibility screen shot:

[image]

Comment: Can you include a screenshot of your toolbar visibility menu? Also, what kind of Eclipse is this, and which plugin provides this toolbar group? Note that the order int he toolbar is not necessarily the same as in the visibility menu.

Comment: Have you tried turning each of the marked entries on and off? Or extending them, to see which might be the right one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the so-called [***Launch Bar***](https://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/LaunchBar) which can be deactivated as follows:

1. In ***Window > Preferences: Run/Debug > Launching > Launch Bar*** uncheck ***Enable the Launch Bar***

The Launch Bar can also be completely uninstalled: in *Help > About Eclipse* click the *Installation Details* button, select *LaunchBar* and click the *Uninstall...* button.